# Why ipa size is so small while pod install the larget framework?

Tags: ios, cocoapods

This is only a confusion rather than a question, that is in my project. I use pod install to install opencv2.framework (350MB+), but when I archive this project and export it to an ipa file, the size is only 50MB+. How does Xcode do this, and can I make a conclusion that my App's size will be around 50MB+ rather than 350MB+ while it is released to App Store?

Thanks for your response in advance.

Comment: compiler optimisations run during an archive by default. They can make changes to reduce the app size and improve performance. e.g removing unused code from the final project

Comment: You need to look at what is taking up the size of the 350MB, which is alot for a framework.  I'm pretty sure Xcode will strip the headers out and probably the simulator `arch`s from the `dylib` given that code will will run on a device only, however it will leave all the device `arch`s (which is later stripped using app-thinning when the user downloads the app), so I am surprised it shaved it down by 300MB.

Comment: @trojanfoe, i connect xcode with my iphonex device and then archive the ipa, as you said it will only generate archs for my device. But how does it do when i want to generate ipa for uploading to app store, will it generate all the armv7,armv7s, armv64 so as to be fit for all devices.